# Xamarin iOS Prevent rotation for specific viewcontroller

Tags: xamarin.ios, rotation, autorotate

Need to prevent screen rotation on specific view controller 
I've tried below-

```
    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        return false;
    }


    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }


    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    }


    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
```

Nothing worked.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this problem with this explanation.

1) In you AppDelegate add a boolean for example

```
public bool disableAllOrientation = false;
```

2) Modify your UIInterfaceOrientationnMask in the AppDelegate

```
  public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
        {
            if (disableAllOrientation == true)
            {
              return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
            }
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
        }
```

3) Call in the controller of the view that you want change orientation

```
appDelegate.disableAllOrientation = true;
```

4) and when the view is close or change you need to put again the boolean 
    in false and put your screen in the original orientation only if you want.

```
appDelegate.disableAllOrientation = false;
```

I hope this solve your problem I have the same problem days ago and this help me.

Comment: your welcome Nikhil, this work, for the inverse case too. If you have a portrait application and you wanna enable all orientation for one view. Regards!

Comment: Yes. Understood the implementation. We can control it through the AppDelegate.
Cheers 

Comment: I just have a one doubt. When i'm already in landscape mode my screen also appears in landscape mode though i had restricted it to portrait mode.
How could i solve this ?