# Xamarin IOS project allows rotation despite info.plist property

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, orientation

I'm trying to disable auto-rotate from my Xamarin.IOS project for IPhone/IPad. First off, I only have Portrait enabled in my info.plist. The screen still rotates so I included all of the code from [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015508/xamarin-ios-prevent-rotation-for-specific-viewcontroller) to every UIViewController involved and AppDelegate.cs (Except for the boolean property and conditional statement) as described in the solution. Regardless, when I run the app on the IPad I've been using to design it, the screen rotates to any orientation. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: How you implemented the code? In your app may be I can help you. Regards

Comment: My app has a number of different controllers, including master/detail pages and tables. I have added the code that Nikhil provided in his question to each and every View Controller in my storyboard (copy and pasted, no changes whatsoever) and then in my AppDelegate.cs, I have my GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations return Portrait always no matter what.

Comment: try this in your info.plist permit all orientation in your device, but control the orientation with the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations that you add, and I think this solve the problem. Let me know what happens

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez thank you but that still doesn't seem to work. I tried on both debug and release just to make sure that wasn't affecting it

Comment: Have you checked all the device orientation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412404/8187800)?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Thank you! if you post that as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check device orientation with (iphone/ipad) in info.plist to keep consistent.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412404/8187800).